# XML External Entities in Android

Tags: android, xml, entity-framework

I am currently working on an Android application (one which will just be for personal use, never to hit Google Play) and I'm wondering if it is possible to use external entities in the AndroidManifest.xml? I've tried referencing another XML which has the strings I want to use but it doesn't seem to be working. Internal entities, however, do work.

Doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE root[
  <!ENTITY p SYSTEM "perm.xml">
]>
...
<some tag>&p;</some tag>
...
```

Does work:

```
<!DOCTYPE root[
  <!ENTITY p "android.permission.VIBRATE">
]>
...
<uses-permission android:name="&p;"/>
...
```

Thank you for any help explaining if it's possible to use external entities in place of that local string.

Comment: same here: `Error: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.` Do you mind to add your `perm.xml`?